# Update ListView items value not working Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

When i try to update value of inserted element in ListView i didn't see changes on phone, but in debug message i see changes. Here my code.

```
 private void chat_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
    {
        foreach (Message item in chat.Items)
        {
            item.MessageTime = GetRelativeDate(item.MessageDateTime);
            Debug.WriteLine(item.MessageTime); //Display changed value(Delta computed on step before) but on phone screen value didn't change;
        }

    }
```

GetRelativeDate // Long function which return delta between current time and time when message was sended.

```
class Message // Model of chat message
{
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    public string MessageTime { get; set; } // This value i want to change in ListView.
    public DateTime MessageDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                FontSize="22"
                Text="{Binding MessageText}" />
                        <TextBlock
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                FontSize="10"
                Text="{Binding MessageTime}" />
```

P/s Maybe i need something more specific for using as chat windows.

Anyway thanks guys i will really appreciate any answers or suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to Implement `INofityPropertyChanged`

[MSDN: inotifypropertychanged Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

---

Sample from the MSDN article:

```
public class DemoCustomer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private DemoCustomer()
    {
    }

    private string customerNameValue = String.Empty;
    public string CustomerName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customerNameValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.customerNameValue)
            {
                this.customerNameValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ChubosaurusSoftware! .

Here how i implement that interface maybe some on need example, or i make not very clear and you can suggest better solution.

At first add to using System.ComponentModel;
Then change model like that.

```
class Message : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
    private string messageTime = String.Empty;
    public string MessageTime
    {
        get { return this.messageTime; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this.messageTime)
            {
                this.messageTime = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageTime");
            }
        }
    }
    public DateTime MessageDateTime { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me

```
List<Model.BeneficiaryItem> oldListItem = listItem;
List<Model.DataType> newListItem = new List<Model.DataType>();

ListView.ItemsSource = newListItem; 


//update the data

for (int i = 0; i < oldListItem.Count; i++)
{
 Model.DataTyep benItem = new Model.DataTyep ();
 // update the individual object  benItem          

newListItem.Add(benItem);
}

ListViewBenList.ItemsSource = newListItem;
```